Send an interactive message containing two buttons via the infobip platform
I have a flutter application that sends the name of the medicine to pharmacies registered with their WhatsApp numbers. I want to send a message containing: "Do you have this medicine available?" It mentions its name and below this text there are two buttons, the first is yes and the second is no.
When the pharmacy owner clicks yes or no, a message is returned to the sender. The pharmacy owner replied after clicking yes. I used the infobip platform, but I still don't know how to use it. I was able to send a normal text message, but an interactive message containing two buttons. I don't know how to do it. Please help me by giving me the necessary code to do that.
this message for send normal text message
Future<void> sendWhatsAppMessage(
      String phoneNumber, String placeholder) async {
    String apiUrl =
        "https://user.api.infobip.com/whatsapp/1/message/template"; 
    String apiKey = ""; 

    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "messages": [
        {
          "from": "441134960000", 
          "to": phoneNumber, // رقم هاتف المستلم
          "messageId": "a28dd97c-1ffb-4fcf-99f1-0b557ed381da", 
          "content": {
            "templateName": "message_test", 
            "templateData": {
              "body": {
                "placeholders": [
                  placeholder
                ] 
              }
            },
            "language": "en" 
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "App $apiKey",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        },
        body: jsonEncode(data),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Message sent successfully!");
      } else {
        print("Failed to send message: ${response.statusCode}");
        print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }

I need help sending an interactive message containing two buttons via the infobip platform
